# Comparing two lists of different sizes and keeping items for which a condition is True in Python?

Tags: python, list, performance, loops, nested-lists

I'm writing code to perform non-max-suppression on bounding boxes from an object detection model. I have a master list of geolocated bounding boxes that are nested lists of `geolocated_annotations =[[(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), (x4, y4)]]` coordinates. The (x3,y3) and (x4,y4) coordinates are the geographical location of the bounding box. I'm using an embedded NMS function in my deep learning model and the results are nested lists of `keep=[[x1, y1, x2, y2]]` coordinates. The results in `keep` do not have the last two coordinates because the embedded function does not take into account geographical location.

I want to compare the `keep` list to the `geolocated_annotations` list and find all the (x1,y1) and x2,y2) coordinates from `keep` that are equal to the (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) coordinates in `geolocated_annotations`. These two coordinates from `keep` tie back into the geographical location coordinates from `geolocated_annotations`, so if the (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) values are equal, then the (x3,y3) and (x4,y4) values from the master list can be associated with them. I need to end up with a list that has all four (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3), and (x4,y4) coordinates.

I have a semi-working code, but it ends up keeping **more** coordinates in the final list than what was in the `keep` list. It also takes a long time to loop through all the coordinates.

A more comprehensive example of the two lists:

```
geolocated_annotations=[[(624169.99807, 4344801.75893), (624170.64013, 4344801.34655), (624159.5841700002, 4344797.0139500005), (624159.1195900001, 4344797.0139500005)], [(624159.9808900001, 4344799.4673500005), (624160.4089300002, 4344799.4673500005), (624160.4089300002, 4344798.887930001), (624159.9808900001, 4344798.887930001)]]

keep=[[624169.99807, 4344801.75893, 624170.64013, 4344801.34655],
 [624151.50361, 4344753.26513, 624151.93165, 4344752.69093],
 [624150.44917, 4344812.13107, 624150.88243, 4344811.58297]]
```

Here is my starter code:

```
bboxes_keep=[]
for i in geolocated_annotations:
        for j in keep:
             if i[0][0]==j[0] and i[0][1]==j[1] and i[1][0]==j[2] and i[2][1]==j[3]:
                bboxes_keep.append(i)
```

Example of expected output:

```
bboxes_keep=[[(624169.99807, 4344801.75893), (624170.64013, 4344801.34655), (624159.5841700002, 4344797.0139500005), (624159.1195900001, 4344797.0139500005)]]
```

Any ideas on how I can make my code more refined and accurate?

Comment: what is `keep`? It can't be a python `list`, since it's missing commas for that. Is it a string ?

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there expected output from the example you have?

Comment: Firstly,I think you are confused between list and tuples. Secondly, I can't assume what ur keep element(as in example) is??. In question,keep is list containing tuples and in examples,I can assume its list with comma missing

Comment: ```keep``` is a Python list, the formatting came out weird but I just fixed it and added an example of expected output.

Comment: Why is `keep` made up of lists with four items? Are these coordinates?

Comment: ```keep``` is a list of the first four coordinates from ```geolocated_annotations```

Comment: But why? It's so much more logical and elegant to keep one set of coordinates per list. That way, list[0 is always x and list[1] is always y.

Comment: It's the four coordinates that make up each bounding box - the formatting of ```keep``` is the output of an embedded NMS function in a deep learning model

Comment: @mch87 I think u are still confused with the examples and expected output. How this (624159.5841700002, 4344797.0139500005) is in output as it's not in keep list. Be clear with the examples and output first

Comment: the (x3,y3) and (x4,y4) coordinates are only in ```geolocated_annotations``` because they identify the geographical location of each bounding box. The embedded NMS function in the model does not take into account the geographical location coordinates, so the output ```keep``` list only has the first four coordinates that identify each corner of the bounding box

Comment: You might have said that in your original post... would have helped.

Comment: Absolutely - I'm editing now to clarify! I can see how confusing my post was. Thanks for the inputs, I'm still learning how to effectively ask coding questions online!

Answer (score 1):

In general, dictionary lookups are the easiest way to begin optimizing a problem like this one. Since you have pairs of floats, a datastore with a dict inside another dict is one way to achieve fast lookups. My example pairs this with a try/except so that, if either the x or the y fails to match, an exception is raised. Note that the datastore is also set up so that if you have multiple points with the same x coordinate, all of the possible y values will be in a dictionary under one key.

```
geolocated_annotations=[[(624169.99807, 4344801.75893), (624170.64013, 4344801.34655), (624159.5841700002, 4344797.0139500005), (624159.1195900001, 4344797.0139500005)], [(624159.9808900001, 4344799.4673500005), (624160.4089300002, 4344799.4673500005), (624160.4089300002, 4344798.887930001), (624159.9808900001, 4344798.887930001)]]

    keep=[[624169.99807, 4344801.75893, 624170.64013, 4344801.34655],
 [624151.50361, 4344753.26513, 624151.93165, 4344752.69093],
 [624150.44917, 4344812.13107, 624150.88243, 4344811.58297]]

datastore = {}

for i in keep:

    try:
        datastore[i[0]][i[1]] = True
    except:
        datastore[i[0]] = {i[1]:True} 
    try:
        datastore[i[2]][i[3]] = True
    except:
        datastore[i[2]] = {i[3]:True}

result = []
for row in geolocated_annotations:
    for x,y in row:
        try:
            match = datastore[x][y]
            result.append([x,y])
        except:
            pass
```

NOTE: I had to make some assumptions about the structure of the two lists because, as commenters noted, your example seems to have some errors in it. If I've assumed incorrectly, just fix your code and let me know.

Comment: The formatting of my ```keep``` list was incorrect but it's fixed now! It's slightly different than your example